# ExpandableListView doesn't expand in my fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I've read lots of tutorial and answer on how using an expandablelistview; i tried for hours, changing codes, but every time I click on the gruopitem of my list it doesn't expand, only change the "picture" next to the title  that shows the the group should be expanded. I've also checked the integrity of the  data I put in the list. Please help me, thanks!

This is the code

the xml groupItem

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/textTitleGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the xml item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitleItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the adapter with some objects

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<GroupItem> deptList;

    public ExpAdapter(Context context, List<GroupItem> dept) {
        this.context = context;
        this.deptList = dept;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        List<ChildItem> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getChilds();
        return productList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, 
            View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ChildItem childItem = (ChildItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView sequence = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitleItem);
        sequence.setText(childItem.getTitle().trim() + ") ");
//      TextView childItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tex);
//      childItem.setText(ChildItem.getName().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {

        List<ChildItem> productList = deptList.get(groupPosition).getChilds();
        return productList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return deptList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return deptList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        GroupItem headerInfo = (GroupItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView heading = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textTitleGroup);
        heading.setText(headerInfo.getTitle().trim());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


     public static class GroupItem {
            String title;
            public List<ChildItem> items = new ArrayList<ChildItem>();

            public void setTitle(String t){
                title= t;
            }
            public List<ChildItem> getChilds(){
                return items;
            }
            public void setChilds(List<ChildItem> l){
                items=l;
            }
            public String getTitle(){
                return title;
            }
        }

        public static class ChildItem {
            String title;
            String hint;

            public void setTitle(String t){
                title= t;
            }
            public String getTitle(){
                return title;
            }
        }

        public static class ChildHolder {
            TextView title;

        }

        public static class GroupHolder {
            TextView title;
        }

}
```

the part of the code useful: Here I tried with onGroupExpandListener and also using onGroupClickListener; I tried also with nothing cause I've read that the expandablelistview handles the click by itself, but nothing works

```
 public class ArtFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnGroupExpandListener,       
      OnGroupCollapseListener  {


FragmentTransaction transaction;
EntryArte lh;
EntryGestore eg;
String tagpo="hoteldescr";
TextView nome;
Button telefono;
TextView testo; 

TextView via_tit;
TextView via;
ImageButton navigazione;
ImageButton phone;
ImageButton web;
ImageButton mail;
AspectRatioImageView hotel_im;

String[] details;

String hotel_telefono;
String hotel_web;
String hotel_mail;

LatLng place;


ExpAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<GroupItem> listDataHeader;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.art_fragment, container, false);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
        lh= savedInstanceState.getParcelable("entry");

    nome=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.art_name);
    testo=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.art_text_text);


    via_tit=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.art_via_text);
    via=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.art_via_secondo);
    phone= (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.risto_phone);
    web= (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.risto_web);
    navigazione=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.risto_drive);
    mail=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.risto_email);

    nome.setText(lh.getName());
        //Log.v("TEXT", lh.getDescription());
    testo.setText(lh.getInfo());


//with this method I populate the list of group and relatives childs(already checked, it works well)    
    populateExpandableList();   


expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_expandable);
    listAdapter = new ExpAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader);



    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code almost everything looks fine. You can try the following to nail down the issue.

1) Add logs in getChildView() / getChildCount() to find out whether there is problem with data provided and whether we are getting the callback by the framework as expected.

2) One more thing is you can try having a simple TextView returned from getChildView() instead of inflating from the layout. I doubt whether having layout:height = "match_parent" in the linear layout could be causing any problem.